# Is material implication consistent?

Tags: logic

How do we know that material implication(and other definitions in logic) do not lead to contradictions? The only insight I have been able to find into this has to do with paradoxes involving material implication, which seems to have to do with differences between classical logic and ordinary language. Is there any way to intuitively understand its consistency?

Comment: The propositional calculus (including implication axioms and the rule of modus ponens) is provably consistent.  Outside of formal logic ("ordinary language") trying to "prove consistency" seems futile because of the lack of hard and fast rules.

Comment: Material implication is a function defined on the domain $\{0,1\}$ by the formula $f(x,y)=\max(1-x,y)$. I don't know what it means for a function to be consistent.

Answer (score 3):

The question is rather vague: What would it mean for a *definition* to lead to contradictions? Are you specifically concerned about material implication, or the basics of logic more generally? Please clarify if I've misinterpreted your question, but it sounds like you're concerned about the possibility that classical propositional logic (or a similarly basic logical system) proves a contradiction. That is, there is a sentence $\varphi$ such that $\varphi\land \lnot \varphi$ is provable in classical propositional logic.

You ask "how do we know" that this doesn't happen? Well, we give a proof. The whole idea of mathematical logic is to study logical systems as mathematical objects the same way we study natural numbers, groups, topological spaces, etc. And yes, we can easily prove that there are no contradictions in propositional logic.

Here's a sketch of how the proof goes. We say a sentence $\psi$ is *valid* if whenever we assign truth values to the basic proposition letters appearing in the sentence, the sentence comes out true (think about filling out a truth table). For example, $(P\land Q)\lor \lnot P \lor \lnot Q$ is a valid sentence. Now we proceed, by induction on the length of a proof, to show that every provable sentence is valid (this is called *soundness*). To carry out the inductive step, we assume that all the previous lines of the proof are valid sentences, and check that any way we could apply a proof rule to obtain the next line of the proof would produce a valid sentence. Since $\varphi\land \lnot \varphi$ is not valid (in fact, it always comes out false), this shows that $\varphi\land \lnot \varphi$ is not provable.

Of course, this is an ordinary mathematical proof, which happens, like all of mathematics, in a logical setting. If you are a true skeptic about things like the consistency of propositional logic, you may not find the above satisfying, because you do not accept *any* logical arguments. To make mathematics work, we have to have some bedrock agreement about what forms of argument we accept - and material implication is part of this bedrock. Deep skepticism about the bedrock, or a search for extralogical arguments for or against it, is probably better suited for philosophy.stackexchange.com.